# Binding multiple csv files and performing a logistic regress on it

Tags: r

I have 13000 CSV files in a folder and I want to read them as one file in R and then perform logistic regression on this file. Also, I need to make the fan column to a binary one ( for the fan values greater than zero, values should change to 1. I am trying to use the following code but it is not working.

```
library("data.table")
library(dplyr) 

files <- list.files("E:/WSU/Research/NN/try", pattern="\\.csv$", full.names=TRUE)
united <- bind_rows(lapply(files, read))

results <- lapply(united,  function(x) {
  DT <- fread(x, sep=",")
  set(DT, j="fan", value=as.numeric(DT[, fan] > 0))
  result <- glm(
    fan ~ T_ctrl + T_out + RH_out + T_stp_cool + T_stp_heat + Humidity,
    data=DT, family=binomial(link="logit")
  )
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: You did not provide a reproducible example so it's hard to know what is going on. Please define "not working".

Comment: 1) What is `lapply(files, read)` doing? Where does function `read` come from? 2) If `united` already is a data.frame, `lapply(united,  function(x) etc)` is applying the anonymous function to each *column*. Why are you reading it again and from itself?